# What function to use to model probabilistic bitcoin mining?

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory

I would like to calculate profitability of various mining strategies. For that, i need to simulate many random mining intervals, that reflect probabilistic distribution of real block mining. What would be such formula that could use random number generator?

Answer (score 0):

Block arrival times follow the Poisson Distribution with λ = 10 minutes. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155539/how-do-i-generate-a-poisson-process) on how to do it in pure python

Comment: ...given constant network hashrate and that no one keeps their blocks to themselves